# Cannot get Knockout JS to applybindings in Adobe Air applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, air

I'm trying to bind data from my HTML elements to my view model using the knockout.js library with an adobe air application.  The build seems successful, and am not getting any security sandbox errors that others have noted, but am not sure why the bindings are not successful.  Here is some of my markup for a select dropdown:

```
<select id="version" data-bind="options: app_versions, 
                                optionsCaption: 'Choose your app version. . .',
                                optionsText: name,
                                value: chosenVersion">
```

Here is the code I am using to apply the bindings.  `ui` is an object declared after the document is loaded using jquery:

```
ui = {

    init : function () {
        log("UI INIT", "Initializing user interface");
        ko.applyBindings(new this.viewModel());
    },

    viewModel : function () {
        this.app_versions = constants.versions;
        this.chosenVersion = ko.observable();
    }

}
```

`ui.init()` is called after the DOM loads completely.  All the variables are logging as expected, so I know the data is in the view model.  The problem is that the select box never gets the  elements as expected.  It's as if the DOM is not updated.

Any ideas to get knockout to work with Adobe AIR?

Comment: Have you checked the answer? If it helped, could you accept it please?

Comment: Not yet.  My apologies.  Will do so today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you've missed quotes in `optionsText` binding property (it should be in quotes because it's an array property name, not a property of view model). So simply update your markup like this:

```
<select id="version" data-bind="options: app_versions, 
                            optionsCaption: 'Choose your app version. . .',
                            optionsText: 'name',
                            value: chosenVersion">
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5aj3pcqn/).

Comment: You were right!  Awesome, thank you for noticing that oversight on my part.  Glad to know Knockout can be used with AIR.